# Spring batch processing supporting infrastructure

Tags: spring, spring-batch

We want to upgrade our current batch processing system to Spring Batch processing to use its parallel processing feature. But the underlaying database infrastructre is old like we are using sybase that support only 256 connections. The application server we are using is Jboss. Does adding parallel processing would need upgradation to underlying infrastructre like sybase (Sybase ASE15) or jboss(jboss-eap-5.1)? Please Suggest.

Answer (score 0):

the database is almost always the bottleneck, not the Application Server, so i would update (or completely change) the database

Comment: Thanks, Being new to spring batches can you tell me how does the spring batch:parallel processing make database connection for processing i.e. opening and closing connection ? or any link where i can find this information.

Comment: it uses the configured datasource and opens/closes as needed per thread, so if you use an application server JNDI datasource with pool configuration it should be no problem at all

Answer (score 0):

you can change the spring batch database to the other that you like!
And then config a business datasource with your sybase

Comment: Thanks, How can i achieve that? Do you have a running example, or link to explain this ?